# Put icon left of H1

Tags: html, css

I want to put an icon next to my heading. But it does not fit correctly..how can I make this fit?

```html
<div style="width:100%;">
 <div style="float: left;width:7%;min-width:40px;">
   <img src="http://superfood-zentrum.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/square.png"  /></div>
<div style="float: left;width:93%;">
<h1>My heading</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: And what exactly is "correct"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you want to align the image in the middle to match the text. You could just `float` the `img` and edit its `position` for a pixel-perfect alignment.

Also you are using a lot of unnecessary wrappers, all of this can be simplified into the following:

```css
#myHeading img {
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
  position: relative;
  top:2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myHeading">
    <img src="http://superfood-zentrum.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/square.png" />
    <h1>My heading</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use *vertical-align:middle*, so if you change the size of text or image, the position is automatically aligned.

```css
.myHeading img {
    margin-right:10px;
}
.myHeading h1, .myHeading img {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="myHeading">
    <img src="http://superfood-zentrum.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/square.png" />
    <h1>My heading</h1>
</div>

<div class="myHeading">
    <img height="60px" src="http://superfood-zentrum.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/square.png" />
    <h1>My heading</h1>
</div>

<div class="myHeading">
    <img src="http://superfood-zentrum.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/square.png" />
    <h1 style="font-size:70px;">My heading</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to do it with inline-blocks.

```css
img, h1{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://superfood-zentrum.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/square.png" alt="">
<h1>My heading</h1>
```